# Can only share one way between MacBook and iMac

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, imac, file-sharing

I have a MacBook and an iMac, both running the latest version of Monterey. From the iMac, I can connect to the MacBook in Finder either as a registered user or using my AppleID. From the MacBook, I cannot connect to the iMac: I hit the "Connect As" button, I get the "You are attempting to connect to the server..." dialog, I hit "Connect", and then try to connect with username/password or AppleID and it fails without any message.

Everything in Sharing in System Preferences is configured the same, the firewall settings are the same, and I can `ssh` from the MacBook to the iMac or from the iMac to the MacBook without problems. I just can't connect from the MacBook to the iMac through Finder.

I've rebooted everything and turned file sharing on and off on both sides.

How do I troubleshoot and fix this?